# How to implement Hash tables, Maps in PHP

Tags: php

I am looking forward to build an application in PHP. In the application I will need a hash table and maps. How to implement this in PHP, can we do this using an associative array? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do hash tables and maps provide that associative arrays don't?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, exactly, completely agree, php is very powerful like this.

Comment: yeah right @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams but if we use hash tables we get built in functions for hashing but with associative arrays i dont know

Comment: Why do you think these "built in functions for hashing" are of any use to you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first paragraph on the `array` documentation, it says:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

So, you might be searching to do what's already done.